# Why is "inline" a noun here?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Inline elements are things like an italic tag, or a bold tag.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inline#Noun

Why is it not an adjective? Doesn't it refer to the property of "element"?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inline#Noun) referenced in the question:

> **Noun**
>   **inline** (*plural* inlines)
>   (*web design, Cascading Style Sheets*) An element that occurs within the flow of the text.
>           ***Inline*** *elements are things like an italic tag, or a bold tag.*

Assuming that the dictionary definition is correct, and that *inline* can be a noun, you are parsing the example sentence incorrectly.

Consider these examples sentences:

> The ***car*** *park* was full.
>   A ***rose*** *bush* was planted.
>   Several ***hot dog*** *stands* were opened.

In those example sentences, *car*, *rose*, and *hot dog* are nouns, not adjectives. They are being used attributively to modify the nouns that follow them.

The Wiktionary definition is defining *inline* as a noun, so in the example sentence it provides, *inline* ***is*** a noun, and, just like *car*, *rose*, and *hot dog*, it's being used attributively to modify *elements*:

> ***Inline*** *elements* are things like an italic tag, or a bold tag.

---

However, it's a poor example of an example sentence because it's prone to confusion. Still, understandably, you *are* simply confusing the defined function of the word in its noun definition because its spelled identically to its adjectival counterpart.

Wiktionary could have picked a less confusing example sentence for its noun definition:

> An ***inline*** can be an element such as an italic tag or a bold tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. The word "inline" may exist as a noun, but that example is of an adjective use.